# SwiftUI Core Data Master/Detail

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, cloudkit, ios13

I’m trying to create a master:detail view setup in SwiftUI where the master is powered by an @FetchRequest (to keep up to date), as well as a detail view that has an optional core data managed object.

How can I create a setup where the detail view stays up to date with any object changes (via NSPersistentCloudKitContainer for example). I’ve tried using @ObservedObject but it doesn’t seem to work for optionals.

Example:
Master view contains a list of favourite predefined songs, I want to be able to tap on a song, and leave a review for a song (hence optional as only exists if there is a song). A review might be updated or created on another device so I need to observe changes on the object.

Thanks!